Locker room scene where someone gets beat up with locks in towels
A random movie scene popped into my head.  I think I saw this scene/movie in the late 80s on tv, although, the movie could have been made earlier than the late 80s and I caught it on re-runs on tv.  This is in the US.
Anyway, the scene involved a locker room where people were showering, I'm guessing from PE.  All of a sudden, everyone clears out and the protagonist is left alone and 3 "bullies" surround and beat him with towels with locks inside.  I don't remember any other scenes from this movie so hopefully this is enough.

Related: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SockItToThem

Is that you amdanz2469?

Sounds like you're after Turf Turf with James Spader from 1985.

At the start of his senior year in high school, Morgan's father has lost his company, so the family moves from Connecticut, where they've been in the yacht club, to an apartment in the San Fernando Valley. Morgan has grown up in the shadow of his high-achieving older brother, and he seems to have a knack for getting into trouble. He also has a stubborn streak, so when he finds himself attracted to Frankie, the girlfriend of the leader of a local gang of youthful thugs, he can't stop himself from pushing her for a relationship.

Three of the gang members then attack Morgan in the showers with padlocks wrapped in towels. Here's the trailer:




Thanks, this might be it.  I need to catch it on netflix to find that scene.  The random things that pop into my head  =)
